# Which algorithm is used to multiply two arbitrarily large unsigned integers in PARI/GP?

Tags: algorithms, computer-algebra-systems

What is the underlying algorithm that [PARI/GP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PARI/GP) uses to multiply two arbitrary unsigned integers (with arbitrary precision), assuming that all these integers are stored as sequences of *N*-bit words? I have downloaded the source code, but could not find the answer.

Comment: The function is `addii`, which calls `addii_sign` in `kernel/none/add.c`. In the finest traditions of academic software, the code contains virtually no documentation.

Comment: @PatrickStevens: in `kernel/none/add.c`, I see `GEN addii_sign`, but I don't see a function that contains the algorithm for multiplication.